# Why do printers use the square "type B" USB?

Tags: usb, printer

Why do printers use the square "type B" USB ?

It seems like a standard they have settled on, but i cant see any particular reason for it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because it's a "client" device** - as to why it's either a USB type-B, or type-B mini or type-B micro.

The host device will have the type-A connector. The host device will be your computer or other device that controls the external device.

You'll notice that you pretty much never see a computer with any other connector than a USB type-A or a USB type-C, just as you'll also pretty much never see a peripheral device that has a USB type-A connector.

The size of the USB type-B connector is less of a concern for large devices such as printers, scanners or external drives (presumably for convenience of having a larger, easier-to-plug connection, or strength issue to make the connector more robust), whereas size is important for smaller USB devices such as MP3 players where a type-B mini or type-B micro are the prefered connectors.

Comment: It might be necessary to explicitly state that _this is literally the point of having types A and B_.

Comment: @grawity you are most welcome to edit my answer to improve it :) I know the quality of your answers is always excellent. I believe the OP was probably asking "why the larger type-B instead of the mini or micro type?"

Answer (score 0):

Client - Host relation is irrelevant for many years. I have multiple client devices connected to my PC with all kinds of connections. USB-A - USB - A
USB-C - USB-C, USB-A - microUSB, all other possible combinations and of course, only the printer has USB-A - USB-B
The real answer is quite simple - it was never worth upgrading. Getting rid of USB - B had only one point - devices becoming smaller. It was never beneficial for a printer to become smaller, it has to have enough room for paper, cartridges, moving parts etc. Since there was no incentive to downsize, there was no point to get rid of the bulky connector. Reusing old components with new printers is simply cheaper.